# How to set a variable that changes according to another variable

Tags: javascript

To be more specific I am trying to make a program to calculates price. The price is supposed to change the more you buy.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Transaction Invoice</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Caprica" />
    <!-- Date: 2014-11-12 -->
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Program name: Transaction Invoice
// Purpose: To do a transaction
// Author: Ephraim Vickers
// Date last modified: Today

// Variables 
var BREAK = "<br />"
var pricePound = 1.13;           // This is the price per pound
var amountPurchased = 0;         // Number of pounds purchased
var reducRate =  parseInt (document.getElementById ("0.02").value);              // This is the percent it is reduced
var noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased;     //Cost without discount
var reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved;
var amountSaved = noDiscount * reducRate;
document.write ("Hello and thank you for shopping at the ACME cement company. This program is here to handle transaction information and apply discounts. For all other concerns please go to our main site." + BREAK)
window.alert("Please be aware that all cement purchases are on sell and, the more you buy the more it will be discounted!!! All numbers inputted will be converted to pounds. Some restrictions and limitations do apply see a instore clerk for details.")
amountPurchased = prompt ("Valued customer, please enter the amount of cement you would like to purchase." );
noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased
reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved
amountSaved = noDiscount * reducRate
parseFloat(reducRate)

if (amountPurchased <= 0) {
    window.alert("ERROR. Your purchase is below our minimum purchase amount. Please refresh the page and increase the amount you are trying to purchase." );
} 
if (amountPurchased <= 500) {
    reduceRate = 0.02;
}
if (amountPurchased <=9000) {
    reduceRate = 0.04;  
}
if (amountPurchased <= 15000) {
    reduceRate = 0.05;
}
if (amountPurchased >= 15000) {
    reduceRate = 0.09;
};
document.write (amountSaved);  // This also returns 0 but i think its because of the reducRate
document.write (reducRate);   //This is the part that always returns 0
</script>
```

For some reason the reduceRate keeps returning zero. How do I make the rate change with amount.
Sorry for not posting the whole thing

Comment: We need to see the entire code.

Comment: is reduceRate global variable? if you dont know/to make it sure replace it with window.reduceRate

Comment: From that code, if `amountPurchased` is less than `14,999` it'll always return `reduceRate` at `0.05`.

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest no, generally it's best not to use global variables. Just make sure that your `reduceRate` test is still within the scope it was defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simple: you spelled your variable name wrong. Just change `reducRate` to `reduceRate` (mind the 2nd e in reduc**e**Rate), and everything should work just fine...

Except that you should also really use `else if` instead of `if`.

So your code would look like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Transaction Invoice</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Caprica" />
    <!-- Date: 2014-11-12 -->
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Program name: Transaction Invoice
// Purpose: To do a transaction
// Author: Ephraim Vickers
// Date last modified: Today

// Variables 
var BREAK = "<br />"
var pricePound = 1.13;           // This is the price per pound
var amountPurchased = 0;         // Number of pounds purchased
var reduceRate =  parseInt (document.getElementById ("0.02").value);              // This is the percent it is reduced
var noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased;     //Cost without discount
var reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved;
var amountSaved = noDiscount * reduceRate;
document.write ("Hello and thank you for shopping at the ACME cement company. This program is here to handle transaction information and apply discounts. For all other concerns please go to our main site." + BREAK)
window.alert("Please be aware that all cement purchases are on sell and, the more you buy the more it will be discounted!!! All numbers inputted will be converted to pounds. Some restrictions and limitations do apply see a instore clerk for details.")
amountPurchased = parseFloat(prompt ("Valued customer, please enter the amount of cement you would like to purchase." ));
noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased;
reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved;
amountSaved = noDiscount * reduceRate;

if (amountPurchased <= 0) {
    window.alert("ERROR. Your purchase is below our minimum purchase amount. Please refresh the page and increase the amount you are trying to purchase." );
} else if (amountPurchased <= 500) {
    reduceRate = 0.02;
} else if (amountPurchased <= 9000) {
    reduceRate = 0.04;  
} else if (amountPurchased <= 15000) {
    reduceRate = 0.05;
} else { //only occurs when none of the others are true: so this is when it's >15000
    reduceRate = 0.09;
}
document.write (amountSaved);  // This also returns 0 but i think its because of the reducRate
document.write (reduceRate);   //This is the part that always returns 0
</script>
```

Comment: @RedVickers I've made a few changes: you should always `parseFloat()` any text input you get via `prompt()`, and it's usually best to put semicolons at the end of lines (just as a good habit).

Comment: it seeams that the problem with amountSaved is not subtracting from the noDiscount I don't see the reason why tho

Answer (score 2):

You refer to `reducRate` in some places and `reduceRate` in others. Change all the references of `reducRate` to `reduceRate`.

Also, your if statments are incorrect for getting the rate. You should use `else if` conditions to fix this:

```
function getRate(amountPurchased) {
    if (amountPurchased <= 500) {
       return 0.02;
    }
    else if (amountPurchased <=9000) {
       return 0.04;  
    }
    else if (amountPurchased <= 15000) {
       return 0.05;
    }
    else { // amountPurchased > 15000
        return 0.09;
    }
}

console.log(getRate(0) == 0.02);
console.log(getRate(500) == 0.02);
console.log(getRate(501) == 0.04);
console.log(getRate(9000) == 0.04);
console.log(getRate(9001) == 0.05);
console.log(getRate(15000) == 0.05);
console.log(getRate(15001) == 0.09);
```

And you should parse `amountPurchased` as a float. Right now it's a string:

```
amountPurchased = parseFloat(prompt("Valued customer, please enter the amount of cement you would like to purchase." ));
```

By the way, two of your conditions will return true for 15000:

```
if (amountPurchased <= 15000)
if (amountPurchased >= 15000)
```

Comment: Oh sorry, my internet connection is REALLY bad atm, so I didn't see your answer posted here when I started typing mine. Otherwise I wouldn't have posted it. +1 either way for spotting the problem. PS: you've got one typo: you say "will return true for 1500" which should be "...for 1500**0**"

Comment: @Joeytje50 +1 to you for answering it in their context. I had already written most of my answer before they edited the question with all the code. Also, thanks for noticing the 1500. I got lost in the zeros.